# How I can improve gtmetrix results

Tags: html

I just checked my [blog](https://theoceanofgame.com/)

using gtmetrix and got the following results.

I have used wprocket plugin for this [blog](https://theoceanofgame.com)  I got following results.

How can I improve or remove these?

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%7CRoboto%3A300%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C700%2C900

https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js

https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to these, you can't really do anything about these links. Try optimizing your pictures instead (eg. with tinypng.com) as those take much longer to load

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions